# How to serialize a class which contains nio.Buffer?

Tags: java

I have a class which contains nio buffer as a data member. I am wonderign how to serialize this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it transient so it is not serialized by default.  If you need to serialize the dat in it you can add your own `writeObject` and `readObject` methods to do this.

Comment: I am looking for how to implement my own writeObject. Any example on nio.buffer?

Comment: I would look at examples for writeObject and readObject. There are plenty of those.  Then you can write the length of data remaining and write out the data.  Do the flip side when deserialising.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to prevent a specific field from being serialized when implementing Serializable? If so, make the field `transient`.